# Firefox gives "Allow localhost to run 'Adobe Flash'" popup when Flash isn't used

Tags: flash, firefox, extjs

I develop an ExtJS site that started getting a Flash warning recently, even though I believe that my site is not using Flash anywhere. If I visit a plain HTML page on the same site, I don't get the error.

[image: top of webpage]

In the "Page Info >> Media" tab it shows only some PNG and GIF images.

I know the popup is because I have asked Flash to "always ask" when loading, but **why does Firefox think that I'm running Flash**?

Comment: If you're using external libraries, did you check them to see if the flash call comes from there?

Comment: @MarcoBernardini, yea bet it is coming from there, but how do you do i find where? Is there a way in javascript to say "hey I'm about to use Flash, but i'm not going to ask you to download the SWF yet"?

Comment: Since Javascript is text-only, you can search inside it if you find the string "SWF". If that flash is not essential for you, you can remove the call loading it.

Comment: @MarcoBernardini Yea, I tried that too. I found that if I use a newer version of ExtJS (my UI framework) then I don't get this warning.